# How can I kill the top CPU/IO process quickly?

Tags: linux, process, kill, top

I find that sometimes my Linux will stop responding, so I need to switch to another terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, and type a command to kill the `top` CPU usage process or `top` IO usage process, so that the system can be responsive again.

This command should be short and execute quickly.
I know the command `kill`, but I do not know how to get the `top`-est process PID or name.

I will add this command into shell alias or function.

Comment: Maybe you should read up on limits, `limits.conf`. Setting these may help you out much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

running `top` with batch mode via `-b` should get you the information you're looking for.

Here's a very messy start to what you could do:

```
top -b -n 1 | head | grep -A 1 PID | grep "^[0-9]" | cut -f1 -d" " | xargs kill
```

You can always kill a process from an interactive run of `top` using the k key as well, since you might not like what it picks...

Not sure what kernel you're running, but [cgroups](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html) may also be of use to you in addition to limits.conf

Answer (score 1):

Keep `top` or [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net) running in a terminal somewhere. In `top`, press `k` then enter a PID to kill a process. In `htop`, move the cursor over the process you want to kill then press `k`.